# Testing if an implicit relation is a solution to an implicit equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to show whether the relation

$$ f(x,y) = x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0, -\infty < x < \infty $$

is a solution to the equation

$$ F(x,y,y') = (y^2 - x)y' - y + x^2 = 0, -\infty < x < \infty $$

The difficulty I am having is not in implicitly differentiating $f(x,y)$, it's in seeing how it can be a solution on the interval. The relation does not define a function however, consider the following image :

[image]
The above shows three possible functions we can use for $ f(x,y) $ lets assume we are using the left most function. Implicitly differentiating $f(x,y)$ yields the following:

$$ 3x^2 + 3y^2y' - 3y - 3xy' $$
$$ = (y^2 - x)y' + x^2 - y = 0, x \in (-\infty < 2^{ \frac{2}{3} }) \cup (2^{\frac{2}{3} } < \infty) $$

Notice the domains don't match up, this is a subset of $(-\infty, \infty)$. Since the domains don't match up doesn't if follow $f(x,y)$ can't be a solution?

Comment: What happens when you implicitly differentiate, solve for $y'$ and plug in to F? If you get something proportional to $f$ you will know $F=0$ on the solutions to $f=0$.

Comment: Implicitly differentiating and substituting results in 0 = 0 which is good. But considering $f'(x,y)$ isn't defined on the same interval as $ F(x,y',y'') $ I don't see how it can be a solution. Can a solution be a solution if its not defined on the same domain ?

Comment: There is nowhere that $f'$ enters the problem. What do you mean?

Comment: $f'(x,y) = 3x^2 + 3y^2y' -3y' - 3xy'$

Comment: @AHusain there is a reply for you from DieHardWalnut, who may not have figured out the business about the @ sign and user name

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x,y)=x^3+y^3 - 3xy=0\\
3x^2 + 3 y^2 y' - 3xy' - 3y =0\\
(3y^2-3x)y'=3y-3x^2\\
y' = \frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}
$$

So for all points $(x,y)$ on $f(x,y)=0$, we have $y'$.

$$
F=(y^2-x)y'-y+x^2\\
$$

Assume we are on $f(x,y)=0$, then we can substitute the expression for $y'$.

$$
F=(y^2-x)\frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}-y+x^2 = 0
$$

so all together if we assume we are on $f(x,y)=0$, we can conclude $F=0$.

More generally we might have been given:

$$
F=(y^2-x)y'-y+x^2 + (x^3+y^3-3xy)*g(x)
$$

In that case assuming we were on $f(x,y)=0$ we would also get $F=0$, but we would have to use both the expression for $y'$ as well as the fact $f(x,y)=0$ again to get rid of the last term.